# How do I access private fields with AspectJ?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am investigating `AspectJ` and its many uses and have discovered `mixins`.

I can find many examples employing pure `AspectJ` `.aj` aspects however I need to use only `@AspectJ` annotations.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:-

I have a class that I cannot amend, it has a private class variable that I need to interrogate after a particular class method has completed execution. This class does not have getter or setter methods associated with this private class variable.

```
public final class CannotAmend {

    private Uri privateUri;

    public final void methodOne(){}

    public final void methodTwo(){}

    public final void methodThree(){

        privateUri = "something";   

    }
}
```

I require an aspect/mixin that can capture `@After` `methodThree()` and allow me to see the value set in `privateUri`.

Is this possible to achieve?

With `@AspectJ` annotations?

Where can I discover documentation/tutorial/examples of how to achieve this?

Comment: It's a pity that you can't use `.aj` syntax as this would be pretty straightforward with a privileged aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within an aspect you can access the private field using the reflection API.

In the aspect you need two things:

- A pointcut to define methods on which the aspect matches.
- And a method annotated with `@After` containing logic that's executed after a method matched by the pointcut returns.

---

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* CannotAmend.methodThree(..))")
    public void methodThreePointcut(){
    }

    @After("methodThreePointcut()")
    public void afterMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object instance = joinPoint.getThis();

        Field privateUriField = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateUri");
        privateUriField.setAccessible(true);

        String privateUri = (String) privateUriField.get(instance);
        System.out.println(privateUri); // prints "something"
    }
}
```

On a side note, using String constants to access a private field is not a clean solution. If sometime in the future the name of the variable changes or if it's removed, the aspect will break.

Comment: Thanks very much, this does allow me to access the private field (seems "privateUriField.setAccessible(true);" is the trick). I agree this is a "Brittle" solution however if this is the "Only Way" I cannot see how to make it Future Proof. What alternatives do I have? (If any??)

Answer (score 1):

Not with mixins, but you can use `@Around` advice to get `JoinPoint` and get field through reflection.
For example:

```
@Around("execution(* *.methodThree())")
public Object getValue(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        System.out.println(pjp.getThis().getClass().getDeclaredField("privateUri").get(pjp.getThis()));
    }
}
```

Comment: you solution is very close, however it doesnt allow me access to a private field. I needed the privateUriField.setAccessible(true); to make this work

Comment: @Hector In my test it worked properly without `privateUriField.setAccessible(true)`, but I think it depends what kind of byte code will generated by `ajc`. As another solution you can use some instrumentation frameworks (ByteBuddy for example) and transform original class before class loading in runtime